# Best way to add spinner to ng-view while waiting data?

Tags: angularjs

I have ng-view where i rotate my partial pages on click, but on first time i need to wait to get data so i need some loader that will spin inside that ng-view until data comes.
If i say `<div ng-view><img src="spinner"/></div>` nothing happend

Comment: i think ui router is something you should take a look at

Comment: there is a useful module with spinners for angular called [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interceptor and show the spinner based on the requested url, e.g.

```
#
#  Requests Interceptor
#
angular.module('yourApp').factory('requestsInterceptor', [
  '$q'
  '$log'
  '$rootScope'

  ($q, $log, $rootScope) ->

    environment = mycs.App.cfg.environment
    $rootScope.showSpinner = false

    _setRequestStatus = (config, status) ->
      if config.url.indexOf('something') > -1
        $rootScope.showSpinner = status

    requestInterceptor = {
      # Intercept request
      request: (config) ->
        _setRequestStatus(config, true)

        config

      # Intercept request error
      requestError: (reason) ->

        _setRequestStatus(reason.config, false)

        $q.reject(reason)

      # Intercept respons
      response: (data) ->
          $log.info(data)

        _setRequestStatus(data.config, false)

        $q.when(data)

      # Intercept response error
      responseError: (reason) ->
        _setRequestStatus(reason.config, false)

        $q.reject(reason)
    }

    requestInterceptor
])
```

And then
`<img src="spinner" ng-show="showSpinner"/></div>`